# How can TcpClient implement IDisposable and not have a public Dispose method?

Tags: .net, idisposable, tcpclient

Just as the title says:

How can TcpClient implement IDisposable and not have a public Dispose method?

Comment: When I'm riding intellisense to get a feel for an unfamiliar interface (probably bad, I know), this is one of my pet frustrations because there's little indication that a using statement would be appropriate.

Comment: Speaking of `using`, I've never encountered a local disposable variable in my life. All my disposables are members. So I'm puzzled by all the `using` rage.

Comment: @CannibalSmith: `using` is a _replacement_ for keeping them as members, for things that are really only relevant in the `using` area. One of its uses is opening a database or network connection, performing the operations you need to do, and then closing it automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). Instead of

```
public void Dispose()
{
    ...
}
```

it would have

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    ...
}
```

Various other types do this; sometimes it's out of necessity (e.g. supporting `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` and `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`) and at other times it's to expose a more appropriate API when the concrete type is known.

Comment: Then in this case what's the recommended way to properly dispose of it? By calling the Dispose() method by explicitly casting it to IDisposable, or by calling TcpClient.Close()?

Comment: @KFL: You can just use a `using` statement - that's normally the best option. If you can't use a `using` statement, calling `Close` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

See [`explicit interface implementation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28VS.71%29.aspx). You need to explicitly cast the instance of `TcpClient` to `IDisposable`, or wrap it in a `using() {...}` block. Note that classes that implement `IDisposable` explicitly often provide a public `Close()` method instead